# Is it possible to have a Javascript variable to have two or more functions inside?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have the following Javascript code:

```
    var Lab = {
        minseat: function(){
            var seat = 10;
            return seat;
        }


        maxseat: function(){
            var seat = 50;
            return seat;
        }

     }
```

So, when I need to get the value, I simply call the following code:

```
    console.log(" Min Seat: " + Lab.minseat());
    console.log(" Max Seat: " + Lab.maxseat());
```

However, it seems it is not working. So, may I know if it is possible to have a Javascript variable to have two or more functions inside?

Comment: Please keep your browser's developer tools open so you can view errors in the console. This will tell you about your SyntaxError. Then use a code validator like http://jshint.com/ if you need more help tracking down the error.

Comment: Anyone else puzzled by the wildly different vote counts on these two basically identical, simultaneously-created answers, or is it just me?

Comment: @DaggNabbit I am even more puzzled even though I put the comma but still could not get my code working.

Comment: Ah! Now, I get it, my code only run during the run-time. I need to convert my code into something that it will run on parse-time!

Comment: If you say so... ‾\\_㋡_/‾

Answer (score 9):

You forgot a comma after the first function:

```
var Lab = {
    minseat: function(){
        var seat = 10;
        return seat;
    },

    maxseat: function(){
        var seat = 50;
        return seat;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a comma separating the keys in your object definition.

```
    var Lab = {
        minseat: function(){
            var seat = 10;
            return seat;
        },
        maxseat: function(){
            var seat = 50;
            return seat;
        }

     }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V4Yje/