# Is it possible to have a Javascript function to have two or more functions inside?

Tags: javascript, function

I am looking at something like this:

```
function Lab = {
    minseat: function(){
        var seat = 10;
        return seat;
    },


    maxseat: function(){
        var seat = 50;
        return seat;
    }

 }
```

The problem was because that the following code will only run at runtime and thus the positioning of the code become a very important as I will need to place them above the line of code (e.g. `Lab.minseat()`) that call upon it.

```
var Lab = {
    minseat: function(){
        var seat = 10;
        return seat;
    }


    maxseat: function(){
        var seat = 50;
        return seat;
    }

 }
```

Yeah, I know this question is stupid and most likely will attract down vote but all I want to know if it is possible?

Comment: Did u just ask the same questions twice, or am I missunderstanding? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350629/is-it-possible-to-have-a-javascript-variable-to-have-two-or-more-functions-insid

Comment: @thebreiflabb, nope, it is a different question. One is putting many function into one variable. Another one is putting many function into one function. (don't know if it is possible to put many function into one function)

Comment: No, you cant put funcs inside funcs. But you can assign funcs to variables.

Comment: I think the downvotes just let me know that it is basically impossible to declare many functions in 1 function. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack, the downvotes are most likely because the question is unclear... I don't think anyone understands what you're trying to do (I mean your ultimate goal, not just your immediate goal of putting things inside of things or whatever)

Comment: You may find closures useful, look up that concept (in the context of JavaScript).

Comment: The downvotes are also possibly because this question doesn't show any research effort (which is part of the tooltip on the downvote button).

Comment: @DaggNabbit I thought that they are trying to tell me that putting functions into 1 function is not possible. However, I thought my question is clear enough, maybe you can let me know where I can improve my question.

Comment: @Jack your question sucks, that's why you get downvoted. What you are talking about makes no sense whatsover. I quote you "my code only run during the run-time. I need to convert my code into something that it will run on parse-time!" But nothing get executed on "parse" time.

Comment: @Jack if I knew what you meant I'd help you explain it; I'm starting to feel your frustration here but unfortunately I have no idea what you're trying to do =/

Comment: @DaggNabbit I think `Jonathan Hobbs` answer is what I am trying to find. Probably I need to attend some communication skills class to improve my communication skill.

Comment: I guess after reading the first question that the issue has to do with  function hoisting.

Comment: @DaggNabbit, I think that `SmartLemon` answer is also what I am trying to find too. But now, the problem is that I can only put one of them as my answer and both are actually what I want to mark as answer. Sigh!

Comment: @Jack Possibly, yes. Your communication skills do have room to improve! Also I think you mean _evaluated_ at parse time vs _evaluated_ at run time, but neither of these are evaluated at parse time either. Both are evaluated at run time, but, yes, the function can get away without forward declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use a function like a literal.

In javascript there is a thing called a literal which works exactly like this, and yes it can have more then one. Its syntax is like this:

```
var foo = {
    bar: functon(){},
    foobar: function(){}
}
```

You can call these functions like this

```
foo.bar();
foo.foobar();
```

if you wanted a function to have functions that you can call outside of the function you can either use the prototype keyword:

```
function foo(){};
foo.prototype.bar = function(){};
```

you can call these functions like this

```
var f = new foo();
f.bar();
```

or you can use the this keyword

```
function foo(){
    this.bar = function(){};
}
```

you can call this like

```
var f = new foo();
f.bar();
```

or if you are only going to use the functions in that function you can use the var keyword

```
function foo(){
    var bar = function(){};
}
```

You can call this inside the function like this

```
bar();
```

If you have ever done OO programming with classes it might be a bit easier to explain.

Think of the function as a class. It has public and private members and functions, inside a function you can specify these, when using the `var` keyword think of these as private members and functions, and when using the `this` keyword think of these as the public ones, also the `prototype` members work pretty much like `this` however I still havent looked into what the difference.

When using `var`, `this` and `prototype` with a function these are all `non static` in the terms of object oriented programming. It needs an object reference.

This is because the assignment is done either when you call the function or when you create a new instance of it

There is a difference between calling `new foo()` compared to calling `foo()` when calling `foo()` you get back what the function returns, but when calling `new foo()` you get back an instance of that object.

So to reference public members of `foo` you would need to create a new instance of it

Just kinda wanted to cover it all. xD

Comment: this pretty much covers it...

Comment: +1 Thanks SmartLemon. I am going to mark it as answer since you wrote a comprehensive answer compared to my lousy question.

Comment: Thanks. I remember back in the day when I started with javascript. Something like this would have helped me a lot. I didn't really know what your question was so I tried to cover it all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but your syntax is invalid.

This is object declaration syntax:

```
var obj = {
    member: value,
    anotherMember: value
};
```

This is function syntax, which is just regular syntax:

```
function() {
    // these are just regular statements
    // no colons, no commas

    function regularFunction() {
        // ...
    };

    var anonymousFunction = function() {
        // ...
    };
}
```

You're mixing and matching both and it's not parsing correctly.

Comment: your members can certainly be functions themselves